# Columnstore index with page fullness 0 and total fragmentation 0

Tags: sql-server, performance, sql-server-2019, columnstore

I have an SQL Server (2019) database with some bigger fact tables (about 200 million rows). I created clustered column store indices on each of them. When I open the properties of the index of one of the tables, I see "Page fullness=0.00%" and "Total Fragmentation = 0.00%". How can it be? I would expect that there is a page fullness > 0% when the index was created. Reorganizing the index leads to the same result.

For comparison only, the values of the CS index on another similar table with about the same number of rows are "Page fullness=96.44%" and "Total Fragmentation = 8.19%".